# How to carry file name to php post method

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am trying to have my code carry the name of a file that the user uploads (with below code) and after uploading, print the string "Your file thefilename.txt has been uploaded" to the screen, but the line prints with no value to thefilename.txt the line is just: "Your file has been uploaded", I tested it with a text input, and it carried the data, but not the filename, any help?

index.php:

```
<form action="uxV637__.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_to_upload" id="file_to_upload"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"><br>
</form>
```

uxV637__.php:

```
<?php
    $fname_ = $_POST['file_to_upload'];
    echo "Your file ".$fname_." has been uploaded...";
    echo "Text is: ".$_POST['text'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $fname = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["tmp_name"], "uploaded_files/".$fname.".txt.safe");
?>
```

Comment: What is MD5 doing in here? Just use [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) and be done with it.

Comment: @cramopy `<input>` does not need to be closed in HTML

Comment: @cramopy — The end tag for input elements is forbidden (and end tags use `/` not ```\```!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [the superglobal `$_FILES` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), specifically, the `name` key of the array corresponding to your file field.

For example, in your code, the file `input` field is named `file_to_upload`, so you would access the file name using `$_FILES['file_to_upload']['name']`, like this:

```
echo "Your file " . $_FILES['file_to_upload']['name'] . " has been uploaded...";
```

See the explanation of the `$_FILES` array [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-383).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$_FILES` reserved variable when you deal with file uploads, not `$_POST`.

You just have to replace this:

```
$fname_ = $_POST['file_to_upload'];
```

with:

```
$fname_ = $_FILES['file_to_upload']['name'];
```

Check the `$_FILES` reserved variable documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score -1):

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
 var name = $('input[type=file]').val()
 $('#inputHidden').value(name)
})
```

Just grab in in the submit event with jquery and append it as a value in a input type hidden

Comment: This is impractical and nonsense